# Use JQuery to add a link from array objects

Tags: html, jquery

I have some python pulling data from Postgres, my HTML is iterating through the content and adding it to a table.

```
<tbody id="myTable">
   {% for item in content %}
          <tr>
            <td class ="playerLink">{{ item[0] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item[1] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item[2] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item[3] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item[5] }}</td>  
            <td class ="linkId"></td>               
          </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

In playerLink I have an ID, 0,1,2,3, etc. What I am trying to do is use JQuery to append a link to linkId that is /destination/1/, /destination/2, etc. I have a funtion to search the table, then another that pulls the ID from the appropriate playerLink.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });

    var id = [];
    $('#mytable tr').each(function() {
        var customerId = $(this).find(".playerLink").html();
        console.log(customerId)
        id.push(customerId);
        console.log(id);
          
    $('<a>',{
      text: customerId,
      href:'/playeroverview/' + customerId}
      ).appendTo('.linkId')
      console.log('added link for ' + customerId); 
    });
```

I added in var id = []; to try and iterate through that, but I am failing at it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can select the `.linkId` elements and call the `append()` method on them. If you provide a function as an argument you can use this to return the HTML to append to the cell based on each element in the collection. As such you can use `siblings()` to retrieve the sibling `.playerLink` and add its text content to the URL that's generated. Try this:

```js
let $links = $('.linkId').append(function() {
  return `<a href="/playeroverview/${$(this).siblings('.playerLink').text().trim()}/">Link</a>`
})

// for demo purposes only:
$links.on('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td class="playerLink">1</td>
      <td>{{ item[1] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item[2] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item[3] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item[5] }}</td>
      <td class="linkId"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="playerLink">2</td>
      <td>{{ item[1] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item[2] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item[3] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item[5] }}</td>
      <td class="linkId"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="playerLink">3</td>
      <td>{{ item[1] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item[2] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item[3] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item[5] }}</td>
      <td class="linkId"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory! This has me almost there, the link is taking me to the correct URL, but for me insead of just 'link', it adds, LinkLinkLinkLinkLinkLinkLink. My assumption is because this runs prior to my for clause in the html?

Comment: Ignore me, I figured it out! Had to remove older code, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help